# how do i use same templateUrl in two difference component?

Tags: angular, components

im doing an online course and in one part of this, the teacher use the same templateUrl for two difference compoment and it goes ok, but when i try to do the same, my code doesnt run, it say  "Property 'is_edit' does not exist on type 'ArtistAddComponent'"... it is not defined obviusly, but it is defined in the second one y wrote it... it is driving me crazy.

```
@Component({    
selector: 'artist-add',
templateUrl: '../views/artist-add.html',
providers: [UserService, ArtistService]
```

})

export class ArtistAddComponent implements OnInit{

```
public titulo: string;
public artist: any;
public identity:any;
public token: any;
public url: String;
public errorMessage: any;
public alertMessage: any;

constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _artistService: ArtistService
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

@Component({
selector: 'artist-edit',
templateUrl: '../views/artist-add.html',
providers: [UserService, ArtistService]

})

export class ArtistEditComponent implements OnInit{

```
public titulo: string;
public artist: any;
public identity:any;
public token: any;
public url: String;
public errorMessage: any;
public alertMessage: any;
public is_edit:any;


constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _artistService: ArtistService
```

i´ve declarated this.is_edit=true;  but i didnt write that part of the code.

////////////////////////////////////////////

this is the *ngIf that brokes the code,

```
<div *ngIf="is_edit">
    <div class="image_for_edit" *ngIf="artist.image != 'null'">
        <img src="{{url + 'get-image-artist/' + artist.image }}" />
    </div>

    <p>
    <label>Suba la imagen del artista</label>
    <input type="file" placeholder="subir imagen..." change="fileChangeEvent($event)" />
    </p>   
</div>
```

as you see, two difference selectors because they are diferent component.ts, but my teacher do it with no problem, so i need a package or something maybe he didnt gave us information?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use a variable in the template which only exists on ArtistEditComponent. That won't work.

Comment: The HTML file you use should be looked at independently. This means that if the `artist-add.html` template references an `is_edit` property, it expects that all components that use that template have the `is_edit` property defined as a class member.

Comment: it would help having a look at the variables used in template, and also the code of both components. Don't need to disclose logic if you don't want to. In my opinion, the error you are getting is not related to using same template in both components. Best

Comment: yes @WillAlexander im using *ngIf="is_edit" in artist-add´s template, it throw me that error, but the teacher doesn't declare "is_edit" in artist-add, he only declare it in the artist-edit template. it´s like angular knows that he is using the same template for both component, but ive checked the template he is using and he is not doing nothing difference apparently...

Comment: @Luis, it's **not** possible. Sure you has two variables, in one you declare `is_edit:boolean=true` and in the another one `is_edit:boolean=false`. BTW I know is only an exercise, but use the same .html for two components it's the worst idea I can imagine, why on earth not check the "url"?

Comment: @Eliseo thanks eliseo i´ll do it and if i fix the error i'll let you know inmediatly!

Answer (score 0):

As you told me, I couldn't find an answer why my teacher could do this in the course, I've followed your advices and created a HTMLcomponent for my artist-edit.ts file, then I used the name of my selector as a element in the artist-add.html `<artist-edit></artist-edit>` and it's running with no problem... now I can go ahead with my course, thanks,

Maybe my teacher is using an old version of angular that allowed him to do that.

But I'm really interested to know the logic behind this, how compilers act to let us know compile with no problem and why his version allows him use this in that way and why I can't... if you know the answer I'll be grateful.